# How to display specific user data from mysql database after the user logged in in java jtable;

Tags: java, mysql, swing

i am trying to develop a java desktop application that deal with two types of users: admin, and teacher 
when user logged in he can even add a teacher or course, and when the teacher logged in the system should display the related courses that the admin entered them for this teacher.
so lets say that we have one teacher but he has 3 courses with their related details 
i face the problem that when i login in the teacher info and i need to populate this details in jtable, their is nothing to show , so after i logged in by the username and password i need to take the username from the Jtextfield and put it in where clause in select statement, nothing showed in Jtable
please help me as quick as possible

form login:
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/test","root","root");
        String sql="select * from user where username= '"+txtuser.getText()+"' and password='"+txtpass.getText()+"'";
        PreparedStatement smt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs=smt.executeQuery();


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(test1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

form comments:

```
     public capnel() {
        initComponents();
        updateTable();
    }
    public void setUser(String user) {this.lbluser.setText(user);

    }
    public String getUser() {return this.lbluser.getText();}
public void updateTable() {
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/examdb", "root", "");
            String query = "select user.username, comments.comments from user,comments where user.username='"+lbluser+"'";
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            tbl1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Start with [How to use Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer,  thanks alot,  i think you just need to say that i need to setstring from the prepared statement or iam far away,  also i hope if you simplify the answer with all respect

Comment: Yes and no, you'll also need to change the query to support it - `PreparedStatement`s are just the preferred mechanism for query a databases now days, so you might as well get use to using them.

Comment: Ok bro, thanks a lot for this support and i will